# Java NoSuchAlgorithmException - SunJSSE, sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext

Tags: java, exception, httpclient

**Background**

I have been using the Authorize.net SDK in an Eclipse project of it's own. Everything was working great. I then needed to add it to my main project. I added the dependencies to the class path and the copied in the block of code that I needed. It should have worked.

**Problem**

Long story short, the code wouldn't work where I placed it. However, it will work when I bring it right out to the main method in the project.

In the place it won't work I stepped through the code with the debugger and found the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
```

thrown at:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Note: httpClient = [DefaultHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) from Apache

I'm completely stumped now. Don't what is causing this error. In Eclipse both products appear to be targeting the same JRE. They also both have httpclient-4.0.1.jar. Note that The problematic project also has some other dependencies that the working project doesnt { boneCP, guava, mysql_connector_java, protobuf }

I don't think the extra jars are the cause as the problem code works at a different location in the project.

Any ideas on what is wrong are greatly appreciated, i've spent the day debugging this and don't know where to go next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Well after doing some more searching I discovered the error may be related to other issues as invalid keystores, passwords etc.

I then remembered that I had set two VM arguments for when I was testing SSL for my network connectivity.

I removed the following VM arguments to fix the problem:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456
```

Note: this keystore no longer exists so that's probably why the Exception.

Comment: Same Problem But mine is a standalone application. How to resolve?

Comment: I got the same error when my truststore was of type JCEKS. With JKS it worked.

Answer (score 13):

I've had a similar issue with this error.  In my case, I was entering the incorrect password for the Keystore.

I changed the password for the Keystore to match what I was entering (I didn't want to change the password I was entering), but it still gave the same error.

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore keystore.jks
```

Problem was that I also needed to change the Key's password within the Keystore.

When I initially created the Keystore, the Key was created with the same password as the Keystore (I accepted this default option).  So I had to also change the Key's password as follows:

```
keytool -keypasswd  -alias my.alias -keystore keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue. The problem was in the passwords: the Keystore and private key used different passwords. (KeyStore explorer was used)

After creating Keystore with the same password as private key had the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

similar issue - had this bug when running from within intellij, did not have it when running from maven.

turns out that IntelliJ was internally using bad java:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --version
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
```

while maven was using good java:

```
/usr/local/buildtools/java/jdk11/bin/java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-08-03
```

probably one of these had some of the above keystore problems.

Comment: I also had a similar problem using different Java versions. The same exception occured, when using a keystore created with Java 17 with maven and Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

You can try un-disabling of MD2 by re-enabling it by editing JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security. Simply comment the following line: From jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2 to #jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error message using [typesafe config](https://github.com/lightbend/config). I noticed that the error message was preceeded by these log messages:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0A|pool-1-thread-1|2023-07-13 07:23:27.048 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:161|Inaccessible trust store: /srv/truststore.jks
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0A|pool-1-thread-1|2023-07-13 07:23:27.050 CEST|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts
```

So even though I had used `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./truststore.jks` when starting the application, it would not stick and the application tried to access a different truststore. The explanation was that `/srv/truststore.jks` was configured in the reference.conf, overwrote the value of the system property in the code, did not exist locally and did not match the one I wanted to use. Then, a default truststore was used by Java, which of course did not have the correct certificates.

The reference.conf could be overridden by `-DtrustStore=./truststore.jks` on application start, no further credentials needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use HttpURLConnection and see error java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException. I use below codes and solved problem.

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"); // or "SSL" depending on your requirements
sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());

((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```