# NoSuchAlgorithm when calling Rest WebService

Tags: java, rest, ssl

I have this piece of code that directly processes the response out of a REST client:

```
 uc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
 uc.setConnectTimeout(2000);
 uc.setDoOutput(true);

 out = new OutputStreamWriter(uc.getOutputStream());
 out.write(posturl);
 out.flush();
 rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
```

When I run this code (actually it is a jar run my a BPEL within OpenESB) I get the following exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext) cause java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
```

I'm not sure what's happening here let alone solve it. I guess this is related to the endpoint being a HTTPs server. I have little experience myself with HTTPs so I'm not sure what's the cause or what to do to fix it.

Full StackTrace (or as full as OpenESB offers):

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:198)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:205)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:361)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at es.myapp.OpenAMRESTAuthentication.readURLResponse(OpenAMRESTAuthentication.java:157)
    at es.myapp.OpenAMRESTAuthentication.authenticate(OpenAMRESTAuthentication.java:60)
    at es.myapp.OpenAMRESTAuthentication.authenticate(OpenAMRESTAuthentication.java:94)
    at es.myapp.AuthSingleton.authenticate(AuthSingleton.java:82)
```

Comment: Could you post the complete Stacktrace? Normally the real culprit is elsewhere and this is just a symptom.

Comment: It should be `HttpsURLConnection`. Can u typecast u.open connection to `HttpsURLConnection` and try.

Comment: Could be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761575/java-nosuchalgorithmexception-sunjsse-sun-security-ssl-sslcontextimpldefault

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I can't do that; this is a jar that's on my web server. It's supposed to work with the endpoint, and I've seen it working on other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! Thanks to @Daniel for pointing out to a similar answer, turns out my OpenESB had these startup parameters:

```
"-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=%OPENESB_HOME%/keystore.jks" "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=%OPENESB_HOME%/cacerts.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

Removed them and it works again :)