# eclipse - unable to download sources and javadoc

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

Whenever I try to open declaration of a method or variable, I get this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Download sources and javadoc".
Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
  at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory
  while locating java.lang.Object annotated with *

1 error
```

I do a command + click on `setSoLinger` here, that's when I get that error

```
final SocketConfig.Builder socketConfigBuilder = SocketConfig.custom();
socketConfigBuilder.setSoLinger(someConfig.getSoLinger());
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are trying to see the source for?

Comment: Although I have updated the description, I ran `mvn dependency:sources` on the terminal and sources now started appearing. I don't think that is the correct solution, so not putting it as an accepted answer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761575/java-nosuchalgorithmexception-sunjsse-sun-security-ssl-sslcontextimpldefault . The JVM that's running your Eclipse IDE (which you can configure in eclipse.ini) seems to have issues about security configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executed  `mvn dependency:sources` on the terminal and sources now started appearing in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This command is magic:

```bash
mvn dependency:sources
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing more information on what the command `man dependancy:sources` does and how it helps the OP.