# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Tags: java, tomcat, https, keystore, resttemplate

I tried many solutions from the web.  But no solution seem to be fit to me.

We recently upgraded tomcat server 8.0.x to 8.5.x.  With 8.0.x Everything worked fine.  But after upgrade, We are facing this error when we are trying to connect to a server from java's Spring `restTemplate` with https.

I did not see any errors while connecting through http.

```
":java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext);  
    nested exception is java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
```

Comment: possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761575/java-nosuchalgorithmexception-sunjsse-sun-security-ssl-sslcontextimpldefault

Comment: Yes.  I already seen that.  but my problem is it worked fine with tomcat 8.0 and failing with tomcat 8.5.x.  Not able to understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

**Some background about recent changes in tomcat 8.5.x:**  (as Explained by @dave-thompson-085 in another post)

> Java 8u60 up getInstance("JKS") (with the normal providers) can read
>   either JKS or PKCS12, but "PKCS12" only reads PKCS12 as is happening
>   here. In 9 and 10 (I haven't yet tried 11) it works both directions,
>   but OP's stacktrace doesn't show modules as 9 up should. Tomcat 8.5
>   (and 9.0) majorly rewrote the SSL/TLS config area to handle multiple
>   certs (SNI) and also align the previously different JSSE vs
>   APR=OpenSSL configs, but to my reading it should still default to JKS
>   unless you (mis)set javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType

**How we fixed this:**
In tomcat 8.0 default value for `javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType` is **JKS**.  After we upgraded to tomcat 8.5.x, they changed to **PKCS12** as this is being used as industry standard these days.

After breaking my head for some time, noticed that, In `tomcat.conf` file, VM arguments configured to use ***PKCS12***. I changed to ***JKS***. Everything worked fine after.

Changed `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12` to `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS`

**Tip:** If you cannot find tomcat.conf file, search for the file that contains string of "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType" in side tomcat directory.  I saw that, Windows portable tomcat does not have that file.