# Getting NoSuchAlgorithmException in SSL Mutual Connection

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to connect to a web service that uses the client/server mutual connection, it throws me a `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, when i run the same code as an standard java application it works great but when i try to run as a web application i get the exception, any idea to solve this issue?

The Code:

```
try {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:\\Sifen\\F1T_5159.p12");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
        
        String soapRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd\">\n"
                + "<soap:Header/>\n"
                + "<soap:Body>\n"
                + "<xsd:rEnviConsRUC xmlns=\"http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd\"\n"
                + "                xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\n"
                + "                xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://ekuatia.set.gov.py/sifen/xsd/ siConsRUC_v150.xsd\">\n"
                + "    <xsd:dId>1</xsd:dId>\n"
                + "    <xsd:dRUCCons>80033703</xsd:dRUCCons>\n"
                + "</xsd:rEnviConsRUC>\n"
                + "</soap:Body>\n"
                + "</soap:Envelope>";

        String url = "https://sifen-test.set.gov.py/de/ws/consultas/consulta-ruc.wsdl";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        
        try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.writeBytes(soapRequest);
            wr.flush();
        }
        
        String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println(responseStatus);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        String finalvalue = response.toString();
        System.out.println(finalvalue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The Result
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Again: when i run it as a java standard aplication works fine, i only get the exception if i run as a web application

Any ideas? Please help, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9761575/14056755

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for your reply, i had seen this post but it did not help me because its relative to bad password, in my case i think that is not the problem because the code works fine with that password in a standard java application but fails when i run the same code in java web application

Comment: what does it mean `in a standard java application`? Pls describe more specifically how you invoke it on these two approaches

Comment: I have to connect to a web service that requires the mutual authentication (it is not my server, it is a government server), to connect with it i made a web service on my client side (with java web application and Restful Web Service [A Web Service that connects to another Web Service]), when i try to connect using that application (with the above code) the server return me that exception but when i put the same code in a java standard application (a java desk application - Not a web application) it returns the expected result, Thanks Marcin

Comment: Hi Marcin, after a couple of days around this issue i finally solve it, it was the certificate, after import my .cer certificate at  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre\lib\security\cacerts (with KeyStore Explorer tool) it works like a swiss clock, thank you very much